# IIS denies the word 'app' or 'comment' in URL path

Tags: url, iis

I'm running various versions of IIS in different environments, and I've found that if the URL contains the word 'comment' or 'app', then the requests are denied with the following error:

```
The request filtering module is configured to deny the URL sequence.
```

But no such request denying rules exist and I haven't found any documentation about 'comment' or 'app' being keywords.

I can add a rule in request filtering to allow each specific path, but this is not very maintainable.

***Is there a piece of configuration to allow these words in URLs by default?***

Comment: Where diid you check when you said "no such request denying rules exist"? `applicationHost.config`?

Comment: @LexLi I checked request filtering